# Implement Chips without search functionality

Tags: android

I want to implement chip something like this: 
[chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv8Do.png)
But since I've a predefined Array Adapter & just need to put its values into this chip & I want to set these chips to a Textview or simply View. I've tried many chip libraries but all of them gave some kind of error while adding to dependencies.
I just need to implement chips for the look of the app & not search functionality so can anyone help me in this & if you have any better ideas then please feel free to share.

Comment: Hello @ritz, according to your points on Stackoverflow I conclude you're new here. The question you wrote is not how stackoverflow works. Please read the how to ask questions on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We would love to help you on a certain programming problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is off-topic, because it asks us to do your work, without showing what did you try. I know how to answer your question, but this would incentivate other users to post such questions.

Comment: well i don't want anybody to post coding for me but just some instructions to help me as i've already tried variety of chip libraries but didn't worked for me & plus chips are basically used alongwith autocompletetextview so that you can use it for better search functionality...i'll be glad if anyone can just guide me in simply displaying chip like thing in a View..that's it!

Comment: & sorry i'm new to Stackoverflow that's why my way of questioning is little immature.

Comment: Tip: You don't need libraries. You simply need a TextView and a 9 patch. If you want a circular image, you'll need some PorterDuff stuff and a little code. EOT.

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankN.Stein. You just helped me out.

Comment: It was such an easy thing, wasn't it? You were just overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it like this with the help of a nine patch image [chip.9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93XxR.png) & FlowLayout:

MainActivity:

```
LinearLayout llTemp = new LinearLayout(this);
                llTemp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                llTemp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chip);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llTemp.setLayoutParams(params);
                llTemp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
                tv.setText("Some text");
                CircularImageView iv = new CircularImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
                ivParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
                iv.setLayoutParams(ivParams);
                iv.setBorderWidth(0);
                Picasso.with(this).load(IMAGE_LINK + IMAGE_FILE).into(iv);
                ImageView ivCloseBtn = new ImageView(this);
                ivCloseBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ivCloseBtn.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                ivCloseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_close);
```

FlowLayout.java:

```
public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup {

private int paddingHorizontal;
private int paddingVertical;

public FlowLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paddingHorizontal = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flowlayout_horizontal_padding);
    paddingVertical = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flowlayout_vertical_padding);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int childTop = getPaddingTop();
    int lineHeight = 0;
    // 100 is a dummy number, widthMeasureSpec should always be EXACTLY for FlowLayout
    int myWidth = resolveSize(100, widthMeasureSpec);
    int wantedHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            continue;
        }
        // let the child measure itself
        child.measure(
                getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().width),
                getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().height));
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        // lineheight is the height of current line, should be the height of the highest view
        lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
        if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
            // wrap this line
            childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
            lineHeight = childHeight;
        }
        childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
    }
    wantedHeight += childTop + lineHeight + getPaddingBottom();
    setMeasuredDimension(myWidth, resolveSize(wantedHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int childTop = getPaddingTop();
    int lineHeight = 0;
    int myWidth = right - left;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            continue;
        }
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
        if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
            childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
            lineHeight = childHeight;
        }
        child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
        childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
    }
}}
```

& then in Main Activity: `flowLayout.addView(llTemp)`

& flow layout within xml file(mainactivity):

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">
 <com.example.FlowLayout
     android:id="@+id/fl"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </ScrollView>
```

Final Product: [final_chip_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMErN.png)